# What printf() returns if the value stored in character variable is printed with incorrect format specifier?

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {
    char x = printf("hello");
    printf("%c",x);
}
```

Why does it print "hello" and then a character?

The program terminates if format specifier is `"%s"`, why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no OPs effort shown. Google printf return value answers the question instantly

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are many resources out there that explain how the formats in `printf` work. In particular `%c` expects a `char`, `%s` expects a pointer, namely `char*`.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` returns the number of characters printed. When you print a relatively small number of characters (127 or fewer) the value fits in a `char` variable even if it is signed.

Your code then interprets the value as a character with code 5 (the length of `"hello"`) and prints its value. This is valid. If you print `x` with `%d`, you will see the correct number printed after `"hello"` (i.e. `"hello5"` [demo](https://ideone.com/wjhdBN)).

Printing a `char` with `%s` is incorrect, because it requires a null-terminated C string. Passing `5` for a `%s` format causes undefined behavior, which in your case ends up crashing your program.

Answer (score 1):

Upon successful return, `printf` returns the number of characters printed. So

```
printf("hello");
```

prints `hello` and returns `5`, which you store in `x`. So

```
printf("%c", x);
```

prints byte 5, which is a control character rather than printable character (such as a letter) in most character sets.

Maybe you wanted the following?

```
int x = printf("hello");
printf("%d\n", x);
```

Output:

```
hello5
```

---

`printf("%s", x);` fails because `%s` expects a pointer to a sequence of `char` terminated by a NUL char.

```
char *s = "hello";
char ch = 'h';

printf("%s", s);   // ok
printf("%c", ch);  // ok
printf("%s", c);   // XXX
printf("%c", s);   // XXX
```